# Unable to open files within zips and gz

Tags: python-2.7, zip, os.path

I am trying to read files within zips but I get
"IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: " 
I suspect it has to do with os.path.join. If I add a print statement of "zname", the full path from the root directory is not included.
I created a similar function that works perfectly for uncompressed files but I am stumped on how to make this work within zips.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to python, so forgive me if I missed something obvious.

Here is the code and error message:

```
def re_zip():
    zcount = []
    zpattern = ('.zip','.ZIP')
    for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(path):
        for filename in filenames:
            if filename.endswith(zpattern):
                zj = os.path.join(root,filename)
                zf = zipfile.ZipFile(zj)
                for zname in zf.namelist():
                    if zname.endswith(ext):
                        text = open(zname, 'r')
                        hits = 0
                        for line in text:
                            if re.match(regex, line):
                                hits = hits + 1
                        zcount.append(hits)
                        print (zname + " , " + str(hits))
                        output.write(str(hits) + " , " + zname + "\n")
                        text.close()    
    return(sum(zcount))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "re_count.py", line 80, in <module>
    total = re_match() + re_zip() + re_tar()
  File "re_count.py", line 45, in re_zip
    text = open(zname, 'r')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'within_zip/folder/myfile.xml'
```

re_zip() was fixed by changing text = open(zname, 'r') to text = zf.open(zname, 'r')

Now I am trying to do the same with tar gz files. I get the same error for tar or tar.gz. I believe the tar module should handle both.

```
def re_tar():
tcount = []
tars = ('tar','gz','tgz','TAR','GZ')
for root, directories, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for filename in filenames:
        if filename.endswith(tars):
            tj = os.path.join(root,filename)
            tf = tarfile.open(tj)
            for tarinfo in tf.getmembers():
                tname = tarinfo.name
                if tname.endswith(ext):
                    text = tf.open(tname, 'r')
                    hits = 0
                    for line in text:
                        if re.match(regex, line):
                            hits = hits + 1
                    tcount.append(hits)
                    print (tname + " , " + str(hits))
                    output.write(str(hits) + " , " + tname + "\n")
                    text.close() 
            tf.close()   
return(sum(tcount))

  File "re_count_v2.py", line 68, in re_tar
    text = tf.open(tname, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\tarfile.py", line 1673, in open
    return func(name, "r", fileobj, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\tarfile.py", line 1738, in gzopen
    fileobj = gzip.GzipFile(name, mode, compresslevel, fileobj)
  File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\gzip.py", line 94, in __init__
    fileobj = self.myfileobj = __builtin__.open(filename, mode or 'rb')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'httpopenaccessikuedutr8080oai_.scol11413101_1.xml'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like `os.listdir()`, the `namelist()` method returns only the filenames without the root. You cant use the usual `open()` function but instead the `zipfile.open()` method like this:

```
text = zf.open(zname)
```

Comment: Thank you! zf.open works. Now I am trying to do the same with tar gz files and I am running into the same issue.

Comment: @trd you're welcome. Dont forget to upvote and accept the answer.